# How to add ImageButton in Map Fragment?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

I try add ImageButton in Map Fragment. My activity_maps.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="info.myMaps.MapsActivity" >

<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="info.myMaps.MapsActivity" />

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonAdd" />

<ImageButton
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageButtonDel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonAdd"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Button add perfect but ImageButton I don`t see image, although the picture appears and I see it in the preview.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're using `app:srcCompat`, you should also add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` to your gradle file

Comment: This line exists in the file: defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.myMap"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2196F3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#2196F3"
            android:text="text1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#2196F3"
            android:text="text2"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/cam"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```